# Is there really a checkmate after 1... Bxf5?

Tags: checkmate, puzzles, defense, exchange

[This puzzle](https://chesstempo.com/chess-problems/90726) on [chesstempo](https://chesstempo.com/) caught my eye. We play as Black:

```
[FEN "1r1r3k/7p/5Pb1/p2BpRpq/1pP5/1P1Q4/P5RP/7K w - - 0 1"]

1.Rgxg5
```

---

**Note:** *the solution is not quite important here, so no large spoilers from me :).*

---

The main blunder here is playing 1... Bxf5. One of the comments runs:

> ...Black is a step away from certain death after 1...Bxf5 2.Qxf5...

They show this board:

```
[FEN "1r1r3k/7p/5Pb1/p2BpRpq/1pP5/1P1Q4/P5RP/7K w - - 1 1"]

1.Rgxg5 Bxf5 2.Qxf5 Qd1+ 3.Rg1 Qd2 4.f7 Qf4 5.Qe6 h5 6.Rg8+ Rxg8 7.fxg8=Q+ Rxg8 8.Qxg8#
```

Is mate threat really a thing here? I believe the mate threat actually begins at 3... Qd2 4. f7. Here's how I would've answered:

```
[FEN "1r1r3k/7p/5Pb1/p2BpRpq/1pP5/1P1Q4/P5RP/7K w - - 1 1"]

1.Rgxg5 Bxf5 2.Qxf5 Qd1+ 3.Rg1 Rxd5
```

I reckon 3... Rxd5 to force White into some exchange, as merely playing 4. xd5 would end up in a mate threat from Black:

```
[FEN "1r1r3k/7p/5Pb1/p2BpRpq/1pP5/1P1Q4/P5RP/7K w - - 1 1"]

1.Rgxg5 Bxf5 2.Qxf5 Qd1+ 3.Rg1 Rxd5 4. cxd5 Qxd5+ 5. Rg2 Rg8
```

The exchange would be:

```
[FEN "1r1r3k/7p/5Pb1/p2BpRpq/1pP5/1P1Q4/P5RP/7K w - - 1 1"]

1.Rgxg5 Bxf5 2.Qxf5 Qd1+ 3.Rg1 Rxd5 4. Rxd1 Rxd1+
```

So, who is wrong here? Am I failing to choose the best moves for White, or is the board in the comments actually faulty?

Comment: How does black respond if white in your last diagram plays 4.f7 instead of 4.Rxd1? White is threatening mate both by means of Qf6 and f8Q, and as far as I can see it's difficult for black not to lose Q+R for white's R.

Comment: @Scounged 4... h5? The White rook is pinned, so the mate on the board from the comments couldn't really be carried out (well, I see no way).

Comment: After 4...h5 white plays f8Q followed by a trade and mate on g7.

Comment: @hmm, yes, I can see it now, thank you. If you have time, I think you can draw up a very nice answer from your comments :).

Answer (score 6):

I Suspect that after 3... Rxd5 4. f7 is strong enough:

```
[FEN "1r1r3k/7p/5Pb1/p2BpRpq/1pP5/1P1Q4/P5RP/7K w - - 0 1"]

1.Rgxg5 Bxf5 2. Qxf5 Qd1+ 3. Rg1 Rxd5 4. f7
```

The obvious threat is Qf6 mate. Starting with the variations in which black tries to cover f6 we have:

- If 4...Rb6 then 5. f8=R#
- If 4...Rd6 then 5. Qxe5 Rf6 6. Qxf6#

Since all variations leads to checkmate there is no way to cover f6 and black must resort to giving up the queen.

```
[FEN "1r1r3k/7p/5Pb1/p2BpRpq/1pP5/1P1Q4/P5RP/7K w - - 0 1"]

1.Rgxg5 Bxf5 2. Qxf5 Qd1+ 3. Rg1 Rxd5 4. f7 Qxg1 5. Kxg1
```

Yet again Qf6 is mate and obviously black cannot move the rook from the 8:th rank because f8 mate. If 5... Rd6 then 6. Qxe5 Rf6 7. Qxf6#. This leaves us with the one last try of Rd1+ (if Kg7 immediately then cxd5):

```
[FEN "1r1r3k/7p/5Pb1/p2BpRpq/1pP5/1P1Q4/P5RP/7K w - - 0 1"]

1.Rgxg5 Bxf5 2. Qxf5 Qd1+ 3. Rg1 Rxd5 4. f7 Qxg1 5. Kxg1 Rd1+ 6. Kg2 Kg7 7. Qxe5+ Kxf7 8. Qxb8
```

It is not a mate but undoubtedly white is winning

Comment: Great detailed answer!